# Running observer for a remote erlang node: making it simpler

Tags: erlang, elixir, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster.

I can easily connect to a remote container, and run a shell node connecting to live production erlang node:

```
$ kubectl exec myapp-2431125679-cwqvt -i -t -- iex --name debugging@127.0.0.1 --remsh myliveapp@127.0.0.1 --cookie my_secret_cookie

Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.3.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(myliveapp@127.0.0.1)1>
```

What I need though is to be able to **run an `:observer` against a remote live production erlang node**.

I can do that too:

1. kill local `epmd` process:

   ```
   killall epmd
   ```
2. forward selected remote ports to my local machine:

   ```
   kubectl port-forward myapp-2431125679-cwqvt 35609 4369
   ```

   I know that my app runs on port 35609 on a remote container, and 4369 is the port `epmd` runs by default, which is the case for my remote container.
3. run:

   ```
   iex --name debugging@127.0.0.1 --cookie marketplace -e ':observer.start()'
   ```
4. select the app I'm interested in from the top menu in `:observer`.

My questions are:

1. **can this be done simpler**?
2. **is there anything I should know about kubernetes**, to make it possible to write a one-liner that'd connect to a remote node and do what I want?

Ultimately, can I make this process a one-liner or turn it into a shell script?

Right now killing `epmd` looks really-really dirty, I'd love to be able avoid that specifically.

Comment: I wrote [a blog post](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/erlang-and-elixir-distribution-without-epmd.html) about how to avoid using epmd for Erlang distribution. It's not an out-of-the-box solution to your situation, but it shows how you could create a custom epmd-like module to achieve more or less what you want.

Comment: Instead of port-forwarding the remote epmd and node ports on to your local machine, you just need to reach those ports using a public hostname from your local machine. If you can do that, you can just use `Node.connect(:"myliveapp@<hostname>")` from your local iex after starting the shell with the correct cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can turn it into a shell script. I did create a shell script for this use-case but am using SSH. My approach looks the same as yours, also I have to kill epmd locally. But I was able to wrap it into a bash script. You can grab it here: https://github.com/dominicletz/remote_observe/

The script also does auto-discovery of the remote beam port. So you end up with one line:

`remote_observe -c <cookie> <server-address>`

I don't have a Kubernetes deployment handy to try but it can probably easily ported to call the `kubectl port-forward <server-address> <port>` instead of the current ssh forwards.